# Is there an alternative to the std::tm structure?

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

I would like to use std::mktime on a std:: tm like structure. I want to do this because my seconds have double precision and std:: tm only has integer precision for the number of seconds. Is there an alternative structure, that has double precision, that would allow me to use mktime on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I note that one of your tags is [c].  Can't help you there.  But if you're in C++11/14, this [free open-source library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) provides all of the functionality of `tm` and `mtkime` with arbitrarily fine precision (nanoseconds no problem).  It builds on the C++11 `std::chrono` facilities and adds parsing, formatting, conversions to/from calendar types, and timezone functionality that far exceed the old C API.

There is full documentation.  There are video tutorials.  There is a gitter chat room.  There are github issues.  And it is portable across the later versions of Visual Studio, gcc and clang.

Lots of [example code here.](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes)

Comment: In the interest of full disclosure, you did write that library.

Comment: In the interest of both full disclosure, and bragging rights, I did write (most) of this library. :-)  I am also available to help solve any problems with it.  And I also accept github pull requests to improve it.  It has an active user community.